# .htaccess Redirect Loop, adding multiple .php extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have sort of a small parent/teacher social network set up for my school. I use my `.htaccess` file to make the links to teacher profiles cleaner and to add a trailing slash to all urls. I get this problem when going to `/teachers/teacher-name/` the link (sometimes) redirects to `/teachers/teacher-name.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php...` Below is my `.htaccess` file. Sometimes if I clear my browser cache in Chrome it temporarily fixes it. I can't exactly wright `.htaccess` syntax, but I'm pretty familiar with it. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#remove php ext
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php

#force trailing slash/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$    /$1$2/ [L,R=301]

#other rewrites
RewriteRule ^teachers/([^/\.]+)/$ /teachers/profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^teachers/([^/\.]+)/posts/$ /teachers/posts.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^teachers/([^/\.]+)/posts/([^/\.]+)/$ /teachers/post.php?u=$1&p=$2

RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/$ /gallery/album.php?n=$1
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/slideshow/$ /gallery/slideshow.php?n=$1
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$ /gallery/photo.php?a=$1&p=$2&e=$3
```

**EDIT**:I have attached a screenshot of exactly what I'm talking about.
[image]

Comment: Below you forgot your `.htaccess`

Comment: You forgot to add your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be because of your decision to add the trailing slash:

```
#force trailing slash/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$    /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Instead of this you may like to write this:

```
#force trailing slash/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#the following rule only works for .php obviously, so add other rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$    /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

And because you used the 301 Redirection, the browser is most likely to cache the redirection, so you may need to clear the browser cache before it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `[L]` to the end of your .php rules to assure mod_rewrite stops processing.

Often when you find that kind of a match for a rule, it is the only one you want to run on your request.  Your last six rules are examples of this, also, except you can do without it on them because they do not overlap each other.

Comment: Specifically, I am referring to the first two, but the rest are optional on account of their mutual exclusivity.

Comment: still getting the same result :/

Comment: "Add a [L] to the end of your .php rules to assure mod_rewrite stops processing." --- it's incorrect

Comment: The `[L]` flag only states that "the rewrite process **of this round** is completed", and the rewrite process is restarted with the new URL.

Comment: Only if the new URL runs through the engine again, like when using an `[R]` for redirection.  To be sure, you can add a `RewriteCond` to your .php rules to make sure the URL does not already end in .PHP

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this again, I see a different error.  You apparently have two rules trying to share conditions.  This does not work.  Each rule must have its own conditions

```
#remove php ext
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php #this rule will always run
```

should be changed to

```
#remove php ext
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php #this rule will always run
```

beyond that, though, are you trying to add `.php` to URLs ending in `/`?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```